# How to create sticky headers using jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, header, sticky

I have been trying to create sticky headers like the one we can see in [stickysectionheaders](http://polarblau.github.com/stickySectionHeaders/). But I have to create it on page scroll and not on div element scroll. As I have some js script running when scroller reaches bottom of page.

Mine is php script which generates the page and there are seperate files in the view
i.e. 
header_view.php

main_view.php

footer_view.php

The content of sticky header is inside main_view.php, so if I try to apply css style **position:fixed** or **position:absolute** and **top:0** to the headers they don't appear on top of screen, instead they appear just after the header_view.php content ends. Also they are not fixed, they get scrolled when I scroll the page.How will it be possible to get it positioned to the top of the screen with fixed position.

Comment: show us your resulting HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Have You tried to give it an z-index?

so

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: 15;//for example
```

So the header will be above the text